# How to stop interval in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a function that emits values continuously.

**What I want??**

If Math.sign condition is fulfilled, I am redirecting user to another screen and displaying a toast message.

But right now, the toast message is displayed continuously, because interval is continuous.

**What I tried?**

`this.subscription.unsubscribe()` inside `if(Math.sign)` condition, but it did not work.

Any suggestions that how can I stop interval in the following code??

```js
startTimer(validUntil: string) {
    this.counter$ = interval(1000).pipe(
        map((x) => {
            this.diff = Math.floor((new Date(validUntil).getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);

            if (Math.sign(this.diff) == -1) {
                //Tried this.subscription.unsubscribe() here

                // Redirects me to another component
                this.goBack(true);
            }
            return x;
        }));

    this.subscription = this.counter$
        .subscribe((x) => {
            this.message$ = this.dhms(this.diff);
        });
}


goBack(requestExpired: boolean) {
    if (requestExpired == true) {
        this.messageDialogService.presentToast('Expired')
    }
    this.router.navigate(['mypage']);
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `this.subscription.unsubscribe()`?

Comment: @martin Inside my if(Math.sign) condition

Comment: So it was probably never called

Comment: The function after that line is called and I am redirected back to another screen. So, this line is above that and it must have been called...

Answer (score 3):

Imho, `takeWhile` with condition inside is the most obvious approach.

E.g.:

```js
startTimer(validUntil) {
  this.counter$ = interval(1000).pipe(

    // turn value emissions into diffs
    map(() => Math.floor((new Date(validUntil).getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000)),

    // this is needed to terminate when condition is met
    takeWhile(diff => Math.sign(diff) !== -1),

    // when terminated on conditions -- navigate back
    finalize(()=>{
      this.goBack(true);
    })

    // just in case if user navigates out before condition is met
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  )
  .subscribe(diff => {
    this.message$ = this.dhms(diff);
  });
}
```

**NOTE**: Yet, I doubt that you need the `counter$` at all. You could use only `message$` stream with an async pipe, e.g.

*controller*

```js
startTimer(validUntil) {
  this.messages$ = interval(1000).pipe(
    // ...
  )
}
```

*template*

```html
<div>{ messages$ | async }</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` method ?

Comment: can you try that? after the redirection, your component will be destroyed and therefore you can unsubscribe in that life cycle event

Comment: I just tried and it does not work either :| I keep on getting continuous toasts

Comment: is OnDestroy interface implemented ?, here is draft i've made with a console.log
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hmmavu?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Combination of ngOnDestroy and validUntil (by Vahid) has helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use [`takeUntil`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html) pipe.
Look at [this example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html#example-2-take-the-first-5-even-numbers).

I rewrote your code using `takeUntil` and `filter` pipe. And I moved the `goBack` function to the `complete` callback of subscribe function.

```
startTimer(validUntil: string) {
  this.counter$ = interval(1000);
  const takeUntil$ = this.counter$.pipe(
    filter(x => {
      this.diff = Math.floor((new Date(validUntil).getTime() - Date.now()) / 1000);
      return Math.sign(this.diff) === -1;
    })
  );
  this.counter$.pipe(takeUntil(takeUntil$)).subscribe(
    x => {
      this.message$ = this.dhms(this.diff);
    },
    undefined,
    () => {
      this.goBack(true);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Still the same continuous toast

Comment: @MariumMalik Please log `Math.sign(this.diff) === -1` in the `filter` pipe to see if this ever becomes true.

Comment: Yes, after few values, it's -1 and becomes true

Comment: @MariumMalik So then the `this.goBack` method should be called. If it's called and you're still getting toast messages, then there's a problem with this line: `this.message$ = this.dhms(this.diff);`. I don't have any idea what this line is doing.

Comment: Yes, the function is called and I am returned to another component with continuous toasts

Comment: this.dhms is just returning a value in time format and is used in my component (So it has no link)

Comment: @MariumMali. I don't know how `this.message$` is working but maybe if you put `this.message$.unsubscribe()` before `this.goBack` it works.

Comment: Combination of ngOnDestroy (Suggested by other person) and validUntil has helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know, the `interval` function stops emitting after unsubscription, I also have create a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfj4dj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to demonstrate it.

For some reason, your code isn't calling the `unsubscribe` method, and I'd advise you to look for the problem here, maybe adding a debugger before calling `unsubscribe` to check if it's actually executed.

Also check that you are calling `unsubscribe` on the correct object, it must be *subscription* and not *timer$*, for example.

But I think it's out there's no doubt that the problem is in the code that you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, seems like what you need is to set a timer for a given duration, try

```js
timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  take(N)
)
```

Where `N` is the difference in seconds between current time and `validUntil`. So

```js
startTimer(validUntil) {
   // duration in seconds till invalid
  const duration = Math.floor((new Date(validUntil).getTime() - Date.now()) / 1000));

  this.messages$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
    // we take 1 more emission to encompass starting emission
    take(duration + 1)

    // once given number of seconds passed -- navigate back
    finalize(()=>{
      this.goBack(true);
    })

    // just in case if user navigates out before condition is met
    // this is needed if you wont use |async pipe
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)

    // map to display time
    map(value => this.dhms(duration - value))
  );
}
```

And then apply `| async` pipe to the `message$` in the template.

Hope this helps